# How to compare two distribution where each point is not from a independent sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, coefficient-of-variation

columns are samples and rows are genes.  There are two groups.
I calculated coefficient of variance (CV) for each group so for each gene there are two CV one for group A and one for group B.  I suspect that group A is more variable then group B.   Is there an appropriate test I can use?  I tried a ttest but that does not make sense because its treating each gene as an independent sample.

thanks you.

Alex